# how to encrypt Rally password while performing CRUD operatios using the Rally rest api

Tags: java, rest, rally

restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(rallyInfo.getUrl()), rallyInfo.getUserName(), rallyInfo.getPassword());

This is how I send the login information to connect to Rally using the Rally rest api.

Can I use Base64 encryption to encrypt password or any other password encryption methods. Please Let me know probable solutions

Comment: Base64 is encoding scheme not an encryption algorithm.
Look into MD5(not safe anymore), SHA-series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rally url is ssl I believe, that should be sufficiently safe for what rally contains.  You could encrypt it on the client side anyway you want but I don't believe Rally will support that on the server side.